# Add a window to an existing MUI Page

Tags: winapi, installation, nsis

**Is it possible to add a window(a Label) to an existing MUI page; like the installer page, welcome page?**

I would like to add a new label to the installer page. My code below adds a new Static window to the window but its never shown/sits above other windows. *I know the window exists because I can see it using WinSpy++ but it sits behind another window.* Also the new window has a funny style "Style: 50000000  (hidden, enabled)" whilst other normal static windows have the style "Style: 5000008C  (visible, enabled)".

**How can I get my label(Static Window) to show?**

```
!include nsdialogs.nsh
!include MUI2.nsh

!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW instshow

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

OutFile "test.exe"

Function instshow
    FindWindow $0 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
    GetDlgItem $2 $0 1016
    System::Call 'USER32::CreateWindowEx(i0,t "STATIC",t "Some option",i ${WS_CHILD}|${WS_VISIBLE},i100,i100,i100,i20,i$2,i666,i0,i0) $R2'
    System::Call `user32::SetWindowPos(i $R2, i ${HWND_TOP}, i 0, i 0, i 0, i 0, i ${SWP_NOSIZE}|${SWP_NOMOVE})` # attempt to push new label to front

    # Attempt to refresh new labels parent window
    GetDlgItem $R0 $HWNDPARENT 1016
    ShowWindow $R0 ${SW_HIDE}
    ShowWindow $R0 ${SW_SHOW}
    # Attempt to refresh new label 
    ShowWindow $R2 ${SW_HIDE}
    ShowWindow $R2 ${SW_SHOW}
FunctionEnd


Section "Dummy"

SectionEnd
```

Comment: Behind which window? You are creating it as a child of the listview, once I show the listview it displays OK for me...

Comment: @Anders when I run the above code the window doesn;t appear, so I am assuming its behind some window dont know which? How did you get it to show so I can get it to show? :)

Comment: @Anders maybe I should create it as a child of a different window and not the listview? I've tried other windows as the parent but I can never find the new window(not sure if it gets created) what parent would you suggest I use?

Comment: Depends on where you want the window clearly. In your example you should just use $0 if you don't actually want it inside some other control...

Comment: Just your first 3 lines worked for me once I click the show list button. The SetWindowPos call did not work because of missing defines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok heres how to do it. Thanks for the advice Anders

```
!include nsdialogs.nsh
!include MUI2.nsh

!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW instshow

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

OutFile "test.exe"

Function instshow
    FindWindow $0 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
    System::Call 'USER32::CreateWindowEx(i0,t "STATIC",t "Some text",i ${WS_CHILD}|${WS_VISIBLE},i100,i100,i100,i20,i $0,i222,i0,i0) $R2'

    GetDlgItem $1 $0 1027
    GetDlgItem $2 $0 222
    SendMessage $1 ${WM_GETFONT} 0 0 $3
    SendMessage $2 ${WM_SETFONT} $3 1
FunctionEnd


Section "Dummy"

SectionEnd
```